# How can check on data be done on each Import in PowerBI?

Tags: import, powerbi, powerquery

What I want is that on each sheduled import, there is a check on the data. If the check fails, import fails and the owner gets notified.

How can this be achieved in PowerBI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that I'm aware of is a [Data Alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-set-data-alerts).

Data alerts are set up on dashboards.  So the method I prefer is to work out whatever measure will be used to check the imported data and place that into a card visual on a hidden page of your report.  Then pin that card visual to a dashboard and wire up your alert to that pinned visual.

Comment: That sounds like a nice trick. Thanks :)

Comment: But I see one drawback with this method, which is that data gets imported before you notice the error. I want to not even allow importing bad data.

Comment: PowerBI won't have that ability to first check and then do something.   But maybe you could run the check in PowerAutomate and if the check succeeds, use that same PowerAutomate flow to refresh the PowerBI dataset.

Alternatively, load the data into an "Initial Load" m query which is isn't enabled to load to the model.  Tag each row as valid/invalid.  Create two new queries that are enabled to load - one that has the main data and filters out the invalid tags.  The other that checks for the invalid tags and can be sent down the 'alert' pipeline.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the method I described that uses power query will actually load all of the data twice.  If there's a way to do your check that's more performant it might be better to do that on its own without referencing the 'Initial Load' query at all.